# Procedure filters a view and give a new view

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have issues with PL/SQL. I want a Procedure or Function (I don't know what's better in this case), which when called gives me a filtered view from another view.

That's the View: (Regal = shelf, Lager = warehouse)

```
 SELECT p.produkt_id, p.NAME AS produktname, p.typ, r.NAME AS regalname, l.NAME AS lagername
FROM produkt p, regal r, lager l, lagerort_produkt p2
WHERE p2.produkt_id = p.produkt_id
AND r.regal_id = p2.regal_id
AND l.lager_id = r.lager_id
ORDER BY p.produkt_id DESC
```

That is my Procedure which gives me ORA-01422 & ORA-06512 Errors:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROZ_FILTER_VIEW (
pid IN INTEGER,
pname IN varchar2,
ptyp IN varchar2,
pregal IN varchar2,
plager IN varchar2
) 
IS
tablout view_produktlist%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT PRODUKT_ID, PRODUKTNAME, TYP, REGALNAME, LAGERNAME 
    INTO tablout
    FROM view_produktlist
    WHERE TO_CHAR(produkt_id) LIKE '%'||PID||'%'
    AND produktname LIKE '%'||PNAME||'%'
    AND typ LIKE '%'||PTYP||'%'
    AND regalname LIKE '%'||PREGAL||'%'
    AND lagername LIKE '%'||PLAGER||'%';
END PROZ_FILTER_VIEW;
```

What if a variable Is null? Would this still work with " '%'||PID||'%' "?
What should I add to get this filtered view?

Would it be able to call this procedure from a binded Java Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure you provided is close to functional, there are just a few of things stopping it in its current state.

I'll make a few adjustments in an example below to get something that will return filtered data.  To get at your first question about `PROCEDURE` vs `FUNCTION`, for this kind of operation, I would recommend against using a `PROCEDURE`.

In this example below, I'll use a `TABLE FUNCTION` this kind of function can be called in `JDBC` in a java app and can use bind variables, ORM attachment, etc. as needed.

I'll include some data that hopefully gets at your questions about `NULL` at the end of the example.

First create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUKT(PRODUKT_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR2(64), TYP VARCHAR2(64));
CREATE TABLE LAGER(LAGER_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY , NAME VARCHAR2(64));
CREATE TABLE REGAL(REGAL_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY , LAGER_ID NUMBER REFERENCES LAGER, NAME VARCHAR2(64));
CREATE TABLE LAGERORT_PRODUKT(PRODUKT_ID NUMBER REFERENCES PRODUKT, REGAL_ID NUMBER REFERENCES REGAL);
```

Then load some data.  In this data set we'll have some shared words across rows, so we can search for similar items.  (I didn't know what would make sence for `REGAL` names, so just used some placeholder geographic names)

```
INSERT INTO PRODUKT VALUES (1,'Walkman','Electronics');
INSERT INTO PRODUKT VALUES (2,'Discman','Electronics');
INSERT INTO PRODUKT VALUES (3,'MiniDisc','Electronics');
INSERT INTO PRODUKT VALUES (4,'Tennis Racquet','Sporting Goods');
INSERT INTO PRODUKT VALUES (5,'Squash Racquet','Sporting Goods');
INSERT INTO PRODUKT VALUES (6,'Tennis Ball','Sporting Goods');
INSERT INTO PRODUKT VALUES (7,'Squash Ball','Sporting Goods');

INSERT INTO LAGER VALUES (1, 'North Warehouse');
INSERT INTO LAGER VALUES (2, 'East Warehouse');
INSERT INTO LAGER VALUES (3, 'South Warehouse');
INSERT INTO LAGER VALUES (4, 'West Warehouse');

INSERT INTO REGAL VALUES (1,1,'Bratislava');
INSERT INTO REGAL VALUES (2,1,'Brinstar');
INSERT INTO REGAL VALUES (3,1,'Norfair');
INSERT INTO REGAL VALUES (4,2,'Jeju');
INSERT INTO REGAL VALUES (5,2,'Hokkaido');
INSERT INTO REGAL VALUES (6,3,'Sakhalin');
INSERT INTO REGAL VALUES (7,3,'Svalbard');
INSERT INTO REGAL VALUES (8,4,'Hammerfest');

INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (1,5);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (2,7);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (3,4);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (4,7);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (4,8);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (5,1);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (5,2);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (6,6);
INSERT INTO LAGERORT_PRODUKT VALUES (6,8);
```

Now we should have various `PRODUKT`s in multiple `REGAL`s at different `LAGER`s.

Then create the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_PRODUKTLIST
  AS
SELECT P.PRODUKT_ID, P.NAME AS PRODUKTNAME, P.TYP, R.NAME AS REGALNAME, L.NAME AS LAGERNAME
FROM PRODUKT P, REGAL R, LAGER L, LAGERORT_PRODUKT P2
WHERE P2.PRODUKT_ID = P.PRODUKT_ID
      AND R.REGAL_ID = P2.REGAL_ID
      AND L.LAGER_ID = R.LAGER_ID
ORDER BY P.PRODUKT_ID DESC;
```

And test it:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_PRODUKTLIST FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;

PRODUKT_ID  PRODUKTNAME     TYP             REGALNAME   LAGERNAME        
6           Tennis Ball     Sporting Goods  Hammerfest  West Warehouse   
6           Tennis Ball     Sporting Goods  Sakhalin    South Warehouse  
5           Squash Racquet  Sporting Goods  Bratislava  North Warehouse  
5           Squash Racquet  Sporting Goods  Brinstar    North Warehouse  
4           Tennis Racquet  Sporting Goods  Svalbard    South Warehouse
```

Now we can test our function.  The original `PROCEDURE` wouldn't work for a couple reasons: It tries to select a collection into a single-record type, which is disallowed, and it doesn't have a way to return the result of the selection, even if it were successful.

By first creating a return `TYPE` that is a `COLLECTION`, we can select multiple items and return them.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PRODUKT_VIEW_REC IS OBJECT(PRODUKT_ID NUMBER, PRODUKTNAME VARCHAR2(64), TYP VARCHAR2(64), REGALNAME VARCHAR2(64), LAGERNAME VARCHAR2(64));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PRODUKT_VIEW_TAB IS TABLE OF PRODUKT_VIEW_REC;
/
```

Then the function.  I changed little here from your original; just to `COLLECT` then `RETURN` the new `TYPE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PROZ_FILTER_VIEW(
  PID    IN INTEGER,
  PNAME  IN VARCHAR2,
  PTYP   IN VARCHAR2,
  PREGAL IN VARCHAR2,
  PLAGER IN VARCHAR2
)
  RETURN PRODUKT_VIEW_TAB
IS
  V_PRODUKT_VIEW_RESULT PRODUKT_VIEW_TAB;
  BEGIN
    V_PRODUKT_VIEW_RESULT := PRODUKT_VIEW_TAB();
    SELECT PRODUKT_VIEW_REC(
      PRODUKT_ID,
      PRODUKTNAME,
      TYP,
      REGALNAME,
      LAGERNAME)
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO V_PRODUKT_VIEW_RESULT
    FROM VIEW_PRODUKTLIST
    WHERE TO_CHAR(PRODUKT_ID) LIKE '%' || PID || '%'
          AND PRODUKTNAME LIKE '%' || PNAME || '%'
          AND TYP LIKE '%' || PTYP || '%'
          AND REGALNAME LIKE '%' || PREGAL || '%'
          AND LAGERNAME LIKE '%' || PLAGER || '%';
    RETURN V_PRODUKT_VIEW_RESULT;
  END PROZ_FILTER_VIEW;
/

Function PROZ_FILTER_VIEW compiled
```

Now we can test it out.
First, lets look very narrowly for *Squash Racquet* `PRODUKT` in the *Bratislava* `REGAL` that resides in the *North Warehouse* `LAGER`(We know this record exists, since it showed up in our view above)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(PROZ_FILTER_VIEW(5,'Squash Racquet','Sporting Goods','Bratislava','North Warehouse'));
```

Result:

```
PRODUKT_ID  PRODUKTNAME     TYP             REGALNAME  LAGERNAME        
5           Squash Racquet  Sporting Goods  Brinstar   North Warehouse
```

Now let's try to exercise the `LIKE`s, by just providing parts of the names:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(PROZ_FILTER_VIEW(5,'Squash','Sporting','Brat','North'));
```

Now it matches with `LIKE` to get a result.

```
PRODUKT_ID  PRODUKTNAME     TYP             REGALNAME   LAGERNAME        
5           Squash Racquet  Sporting Goods  Bratislava  North Warehouse
```

But *Squash Racquet*s and *Tennis Racquet*s are in totally different `REGAL`s.  To just search for any kind of Racquet, you indeed can rely on `NULL`-handling to help-out.

Here we'll just search for any *Racquet*, in any `REGAL/LAGER/PRODUKT`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(PROZ_FILTER_VIEW(NULL,'Racquet','Sporting',NULL,NULL));
```

The return includes ALL *Squash Racquets* and *Tennis Racquets*:

```
PRODUKT_ID  PRODUKTNAME     TYP             REGALNAME   LAGERNAME        
5           Squash Racquet  Sporting Goods  Bratislava  North Warehouse  
5           Squash Racquet  Sporting Goods  Brinstar    North Warehouse  
4           Tennis Racquet  Sporting Goods  Svalbard    South Warehouse  
4           Tennis Racquet  Sporting Goods  Hammerfest  West Warehouse
```

If you just search by `PRODUKT_ID`, that works too:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(PROZ_FILTER_VIEW(5,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL));

PRODUKT_ID  PRODUKTNAME     TYP             REGALNAME   LAGERNAME        
5           Squash Racquet  Sporting Goods  Brinstar    North Warehouse  
5           Squash Racquet  Sporting Goods  Bratislava  North Warehouse
```

Hopefully this gets at your 2nd set of questions about `NULL` and `LIKE`.

To wrap up, I'd just have a couple other suggestions:

- As written, this is case sensitive, so something like the below fails:

  `SELECT * FROM TABLE(PROZ_FILTER_VIEW(NULL,'racquet',NULL,NULL,NULL));`

If you'd like case-insensitivity, you might consider `UPPER`ing in the `LIKE` comparisons.

- You might consider optional parameters.
- Depending on your indexing strategy and data volume, this kind of query with numerous `LIKE` can have trouble scaling-up and can be costly to the database.  I'd suggest benchmarking against oversized test data-sets and consider `TEXT` indexes, parameter restrictions, reconsidering the double `%%` any-like match, etc. if needed.

Comment: This is exactly What I needed. I am a beginner.. some Things are new for me.

Comment: Thanks @LeonardTraeger  Glad to hear it.  If anything I can clarify just let me know.  If this (or another answer) has answered your question, please consider accepting an answer.  Thanks